Print incrementing integer as part of a string
I am trying to get a list of scores from user input. I want each prompt to include the current game number, which will increment from 1 to the total number of games. For example, if the user wants to input 3 games, the prompts should look like this:
score for game 1
score for game 2
score for game 3

Here's my code without the incrementing:
n = int(input("enter total number of games "))
games = []
for i in range(n):
    x = int(input("score for game 1 "))
    games.append(x)

How can I modify this so that the "1" increments from 1 to n?

This question is similar to: How can I increment the numerical part of a string?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Don't try to manually increment anything - since you're using a for loop over a range, you can use the value of the iteration variable (i) as your "incrementing" variable. You'll have to adjust the bounds from [0, n-1] to [1, n], which you can do in your for statement. Then you can use an f-string for the actual printing; it's the most concise and (to me) most readable way to use an int variable in a string.
n = int(input("enter total number of games "))
games = []
for i in range(1, n+1):
    x = int(input(f"score for game {i} "))
    games.append(x) 


Amazing this is a great solution!

@AdnanAli Glad it helped. Since you're new here, check out What should I do when someone answers my question?
